# $WW\to t\bar{t}$ growth

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, scattering, higgs, quarks

I was told recently that "it is well known that processes like $WW\to t\bar{t}$ ($t$ being a top, or any massive fermion) grows linearly with the energy in the absence of an Higgs boson." Does anyone know of a reference? The only ones I can find regarding the growth of $WW \to f\bar{f}$ are about the old argument for having a neutral current, i.e. $WW \to f\bar{f}$ cross-section grows if $Z$-mediated diagrams are not included.

Comment: In case you're just looking for support of the unitarity violation argument, the more common example is that WW->WW scattering violates unitarity at the TeV scale.

Comment: @luksen Thanks, but I already know about the WW->WW scattering (see arxiv:1107.1501).

Comment: I should say that I don't believe that the Higgs has anything to do with the growth of WW -> ffbar, since the chiralities of the outgoing fermions are different with and without the Higgs. Still, I may have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The control of high-energy behavior in the $\bar{f}fWW$ amplitudes is part of the cornerstone of the SSB gauge theories, explored early on by  Llewellyn Smith, 
[Phys Lett B46 (1973)233-236, High energy behaviour and gauge symmetry](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(73)90692-8).

Essentially, he demonstrates that *both the gauge couplings of the vector bosons and one or more Higgses with the suitable couplings* are required to control unlimited growth of the amp with high energy (*s*).

I don't know of any quick and ready intuition for the result, but it is sound and complete. Since BJ was involved in its inception, maybe his subsequent pedagogical writings have something friendlier.

- Concerning your chiralities' reservations' comment, yes, you *have* missed the *Z*-exchange chiralities. Unlike *W*-couplings only operative on left-handed fermions and right-handed antifermions, *Z*-couplings involve *both* left-handed and right-handed fermions, and so, in fact, *need* a L-R channel provided by the Higgs, to cancel their high energy limit.